# Which is correct: linguistic development on/of human beings

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence, sentence-meaning, portuguese

I came across a very hard to translate sentence in a text written in Portuguese and I need some help with the semantics:

> that suggested that subjective consciousness was developed in relation to the linguistic development **on** human beings

or

> that suggested that subjective consciousness was developed in relation to the linguistic development **of** human beings

In which case it is the linguistic of human beings getting more complex and not the development of human beings by linguistic?

Comment: You can have the linguistic development of human beings, or you can have the linguistic development in human beings. But a linguistic development on human beings is not a thing. It's hilariously wrong. As to the other meaning you are trying to avoid, you're reading too much into it. Nobody would misread that sentence that way. I had to try really hard to at all see what you mean, even after you explained it. So you shouldn't worry about that. (As a bonus fact, "by linguistic" is not English, either. The noun is "linguistics", with an S. "Linguistic" is only an adjective.)

Answer (score 1):

It's case two. If somebody was improving humans, or developing them, then it would be *on* human beings, but it seems that you are talking about the development *of* human beings, and not development *on* them.

Example of *on*:

> we have begun development *on* a new flavour of ketchup
>
> i.e. we are making a new flavor of ketchup

Example of *of*:

> we are researching the development *of* ketchup flavours over time
>
> i.e. we are looking at how ketchup flavours have changed

Hope this helps!